# How to pass parameter by variable in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-closure-compiler

I am getting warning message and not compiled while optimizing my JS through [closure-compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home) in advanced mode.

> JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: actual parameter 1 of
>   Document.prototype.getElementById does not match formal parameter

my js function to change class for div

```
for (kx = 1; kx <= 5;kx=kx+1) {
document.getElementById(kx).className='newclass';
    }
```

in HTML I having five div as follows

```
<div id='1' class ='first'> contents </div>
<div id='2' class ='first'> contents </div>
<div id='3' class ='first'> contents </div>
<div id='4' class ='first'> contents </div>
<div id='5' class ='first'> contents </div>
```

this code working in normal case (without compress / optimization), but while trying to optimize it showing warning/error, How can I fix it?

Comment: I would consider this a bug in Closure, because what you're doing will work perfectly well in an actual browser. Pre-HTML5 specs held that "id" properties should be valid identifiers, but in HTML5 (and in all modern browsers) that's not the case - any string without embedded spaces is valid.

Comment: @Pointy I think it has more to do with the [type of the argument](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29539934/621962).

Comment: @canon yes, I agree, but my point is that the warning is just noise since (as you note) the code will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closure expects you to pass a `string` to `document.getElementById()` rather than a `number`.

> JSC_TYPE_MISMATCH: actual parameter 1 of
>   Document.prototype.getElementById does not match formal parameter
>   found   : number
>   **required: string**
>  at line 3 character 24
>
> ```
> document.getElementById(kx).className='newclass';
> ```

So, explicitly converting `kx` to a `string`<sup>1</sup> should remove that warning:

```
for (kx = 1; kx <= 5; kx++) {
    document.getElementById(kx.toString()).className='newclass';
}
```

I don't know that I'd bother, though; the original actually compiles. You got a warning rather than an error (I suspect) because a numeric argument will simply be coerced into a string. That said, if your environment promotes warnings to errors, by all means... jump through the hoops.

<sub><sup>1</sup> It's worth noting that you can convert a number to a string by simply concatenating with an empty string, i.e.: `''+kx`, and allowing [type-coercion](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.6.1) to do its thing. I've elected to use `Number.prototype.toString()` because, for the purspose of the example, the method call more clearly demonstrates the intent.</sub>